# broadcasting data to mobile devices

Tags: model-view-controller, mobile

I working on a project were mobile users can receive alerts based on diferent factors, the server side will be implemented using the MVC framework.

My question is regarding the client side; what would be the most efficient way to send the alerts to the clients? is there any way to broadcast the alerts to each device or do I have to set up some system where each device pulls the data from the server on an interval of mins/seconds? I am afraid pulling the data every X secs/mins would create an unnesesary overhead on the mobile devices.

One way would be using SMS but SMS gateway services are expensive and not on my budget right now.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tried it, but this service might work for you:

http://www.airgramapp.com/api

It is free for limited use.  Downside is it appears to be a separate install on the mobile device. This *might* means less control of the content of the message or its look.  Upside is it looks quick and easy if you just need a proof of concept at this point.